# Listening for JavaScript Media Queries in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, addeventlistener

I am trying to implement the media query concept found [here](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-javascript-media-queries/) in React. With what's shown below I am getting the following:

```
TypeError: isMobile.addListener is not a function
```

```
function App() {
    // Saving current page to state 
    let location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        useStore.setState({ currentPage: location })
    }, [location]);

    // Check if viewing in landscape on mobile
    const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 830px)").matches;

    const setOrientation = (e) => {
        if (e.isMobile) {
            if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
                // is not landscape
            } else{
                // is landscape
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setOrientation(isMobile)
        isMobile.addListener(setOrientation)

        return () => isMobile.removeEventListener(setOrientation)
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App"></div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are setting const isMobile to type Boolean (true/false) instead of the upper level Object (function) window.matchMedia('string_query')

Try something like this:

```sh
const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 830px)")

typeof isMobile
"object"

isMobile.matches
true

function handleTabletChange(e) {
  // Check if the media query is true
  if (e.matches) {
    // Then log the following message to the console
    console.log('Media Query Matched!')
  }
}

isMobile.addListener(handleTabletChange)
```

What your code is doing:

```sh
const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 830px)").matches

typeof isMobile
"boolean"

isMobile.matches
undefined

function handleTabletChange(e) {
  // Check if the media query is true
  if (e.matches) {
    // Then log the following message to the console
    console.log('Media Query Matched!')
  }
}

isMobile.addListner(handleTabletChange)

Uncaught TypeError: isMobile.addListner is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) `matches` method returns a boolean value.

you should only return your MediaQueryList to be able to [addListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) to it later:

```
const isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 830px)")
```